# Geolocation Map JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have some JavaScript code to get a map from Google Maps, but it does not show the current location of client when they access it.

```
    initialize: function(options) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'setCenter');
        var view = this;
        if ($('#map-top-wrapper').length == 0) return;
        view.options = _.extend(this, options);
        view.center = new google.maps.LatLng(this.options.latitude, this.options.longitude);
        view.map_options = {
            'zoom': parseInt(ae_globals.map_zoom),
            'center': view.center,
            'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            // 'scrollwheel': false 
            'scrollwheel': true,
            'zoomControl': true
        };
```

Please help me set the geolocation; when the user accesses my website, the map should show their curent location.

Thanks!

Comment: follow this example. **https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation** 

please search before answer

Comment: Hi Hiếu ! Hiện nay thì nó tự lấy thông tin Location của site  rồi ! Cái mình muốn là khi vào nó tự show map ngay vị trí người dùng, chứ không phải show theo cái vị trí cài đặt sẵn hay là thông báo họ đang ở vị trí nào !

Answer (score 0):

In url: **https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation** 
You can see from function **handleNoGeolocation** at line  **map.setCenter(options.position);**

This is my function to set center map, with lat, lng and zoom level, default zoom level = 7.

```
function SetCenterMap(lat, lng, zoom) {
    if (typeof (zoom) === 'undefined')
        zoom = 7;
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    map.setZoom(zoom);
    map.setCenter(center);
}
```

try this I hope it will be help you :)

Answer (score 0):

it is not working, the map not show at current location of client !

This is my js file :

```
(function(Views, Models, $, Backbone) {
Views.Map = Backbone.View.extend({
    // load info window content template
    events: {},
    // initilize view
    initialize: function(options) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'setCenter');
        var view = this;
        if ($('#map-top-wrapper').length == 0) return;
        view.options = _.extend(this, options);
        view.center = new google.maps.LatLng(this.options.latitude, this.options.longitude);
        view.map_options = {
            'zoom': parseInt(ae_globals.map_zoom),
            'center': view.center,
            'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            // 'scrollwheel': false 
            'scrollwheel': false,
            'zoomControl': true
        };

        this.template = _.template($('#ae_info_content_template').html());
        // map marker colections
        view.markers = [];
        // map marker cluster
        view.markerCluster = [];
        // init map info window
        var iw1 = new InfoBubble({
            content: '',
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-35, 151),
            shadowStyle: 1,
            padding: 0,
            borderRadius: 5,
            arrowSize: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderColor: '#ccc',
            disableAutoPan: false,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            arrowStyle: 0,
            maxWidth: 600,
            minWidth: 400,
            minHeight: 90,
            maxHeight: 400,
            padding: 0,
            autoPan: true
        });
        view.infoWindow = iw1;
        // Map for default save-widget
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-top-wrapper"), view.map_options);

        this.categories = [];
        if ($('#de-categories-data').length > 0) {
            this.categories = JSON.parse($('#de-categories-data').html());
        }
        this.initMapIcon();
        // render map
        this.renderMap();
        this.nearby = false;
        if ($('#nearby_location').length > 0) {
            this.nearby = true;
        }
        //bind event when user give location
        // AE.pubsub.on('de:getCurrentPosition', this.setCenter, this);
    },

    initMapIcon: function() {
        var view = this;
        this.icons = {};
        this.colors = {};
        this.fontClass = {};
        _.each(this.categories, function(element, index) {
            var icon = {
                path: 'M 50 -119.876 -50 -119.876 -50 -19.876 -13.232 -19.876 0.199 0 13.63 -19.876 50 -19.876 Z',
                fillColor: element.color,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                scale: 0.3,
                strokeColor: element.color,
                strokeWeight: 0
            };
            view.icons[element.term_id] = icon;
            view.colors[element.term_id] = element.color;
            view.fontClass[element.term_id] = element.icon;
        });
    },
    /**
     * render map call ajax to get marker data
     * @author Dakachi
     */
    renderMap: function(data) {
        var view = this,
            data = {
                action: 'de_get_map_data'
            };
        view.markers = [];
        /**
         * ajax request get all place on map
         */
        if ($('.main-pagination').length > 0) {
            var query = JSON.parse($('.main-pagination .ae_query').html());
            data.query = query;
        }
        var i = 100,
            k = 1;
        if($('#total_place').length > 0 ) {
            i = JSON.parse( $('#total_place').html() );
            i = i.number;
        }
        var cat = '';
        if($('#place_cat_slug').length > 0){
            cat = JSON.parse( $('#place_cat_slug').html() );
            cat = cat.slug;
        }
        for (var j = i; j >= 0; j = (j-50) ) {
            data.paged = k;
            data.showposts = 50;
            data.place_category = cat;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: ae_globals.ajaxURL,
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() {},
                success: function(resp) {
                    if (typeof resp.data !== 'undefined' && resp.data.length > 0 ) {
                        var data = resp.data;
                        // bind data markers to map
                        view.ajaxSuccess(data);
                    }
                }
            });
            k++;
        }
    },
    /**
     * after successful request map data
     */
    ajaxSuccess: function(data) {
        var view = this;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var content = view.template(data[i]),
                // place latitude and longitude
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].et_location_lat, data[i].et_location_lng),
                // get place category
                term = data[i]['place_category'][0],
                color = view.colors[term],
                fontClass = view.fontClass[term],
                icon = view.icons[term];
            bounds.extend(latLng);
            if (typeof color === 'undefined') {
                color = '#F59236';
            }
            if (typeof fontClass === 'undefined') {
                fontClass = 'fa-map-marker';
            }
            if (typeof icon === 'undefined') {
                var icon = {
                    path: 'M 50 -119.876 -50 -119.876 -50 -19.876 -13.232 -19.876 0.199 0 13.63 -19.876 50 -19.876 Z',
                    fillColor: '#F59236',
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                    scale: 0.3,
                    strokeColor: '#F59236',
                    strokeWeight: 0
                };
            }
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: latLng,
                // label by place category color and icon class
                labelContent: "<span><i style='color:" + color + ";' class='fa " + fontClass + "'></i><span>",
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 31),
                labelClass: "map-labels", // the CSS class for the label
                labelStyle: {
                    opacity: 1.0
                },
                icon: icon
            });

            // // set marker content using in multichoice
            marker.content = content;
            view.markers.push(marker);
            // attach info window
            view.attachMarkerInfowindow(marker, content, data[i]);

            if (typeof view.model !== 'undefined' && view.model.get('ID') == data[i]['ID']) {
                view.map.setCenter(latLng);
                /**
                 * set conten for info window
                 */
                view.infoWindow.setContent(content);
                // set border color for info window
                view.infoWindow.setBorderColor(color);
                // open info window 
                view.infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
                view.map.setZoom(15);
            }
        }
        // init map cluster
        view.markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(view.map, view.markers, {
            zoomOnClick: true,
            gridSize: 20
        });
        // bind event click on cluster for multi marker in a position
        view.markerCluster.onClick = function(icon) {
            return view.multiChoice(icon.cluster_);
        }
        if (typeof view.model === 'undefined' && parseInt(ae_globals.fitbounds)) {
            //  Fit these bounds to the map
            view.map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    },
```

Comment: ?? in your code doesn't have any code get client location. ??.